# How to get start with Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: appcelerator-mobile

I am very new to Appcelerator Titanium. I followed the instructions and could able to successfully install the software and android sdk(only android for the time being). But as the site suggested when I tried to import and run the KitchenSink, I can see nothing on my emulator. It is not running. What will be the issue?
Or are there any other simple project ? Please help me

Regards

Answer (score 1):

**KitchenSink** is some heavy application.

So start your emulator and then run project from Titanium Studio, wait for some time. If it is not running after this, check your android SDKsetting `(Window->Preferences->Titanium Studio->Titanium)`also check your java environment variable setting.

When your application setting will get properly done, your application will definitely execute.